# Asignar ruta a un archivo en carpeta de proyecto c#

Tags: c#

Disculpen el título que no sabía bien como ponerle.

Actualmente estoy generando reportes con Crystal Report mediante C#. No he tenido problemas con esto pero de la forma en que lo hago, tengo que darle la ruta de dónde está el archivo **.rpt**, un ejemplo:

```
public void GenerarReporte(DSCobroPorcentaje ds)
{
    ReportDocument rep = new ReportDocument();
    rep.Load(@"D:\Area de Trabajo SM\Rentas v2\Rentasv2\Informes\CRCobroPorcentaje.rpt");
    rep.SetDataSource(ds);
    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rep;
}
```

Mi duda es: cuando compile el proyecto esta ruta se va a cambiar por donde se instale la aplicación o va a ir a buscarla ahí donde la tengo? No he hecho la prueba y quizás debería pero quería saber si a alguno le a pasado.

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Cuando compiles el programa cogerá la ruta que tu le has puesto en el código, es decir, esta: `D:\Area de Trabajo SM\Rentas v2\Rentasv2\Informes\CRCobroPorcentaje.rpt`

Comment: a ok, pensé que después iba a tener algún problema con eso. Gracias por la aclaración

Answer (score 3):

La ruta si la defines como en el codigo que nos muestras va a quedar fija

Si necesitas que sea dinamica deberias poder configurarla en el `app.config` o si es una ruta relativa a la aplicacion, o sea, que los .rpt estaran junto al .exe o en una carpeta junto a este podrias usar

```
 string rptFile = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"Informes\CRCobroPorcentaje.rpt");
 rep.Load(rptFile);
```

de esta forma tomara la primer parte donde esta la app ejecutando

[Application.StartupPath](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath?view=netframework-4.8)

Nota: ten en cuanta que si inicias desde el Visual Studio, el .exe se copia a la carpeta `\bin\Debug` con lo cual deberias poner alli los rpt para que funcione la ruta relativa desde donde eejcuta

Comment: voy a compilar el proyecto y lo voy a instalar para ver dónde quedan los .rpt

Comment: consulta... dónde se instalan las aplicaciones que uno crea en visual studio? Nunca e definido eso

Comment: depende que tool uses en la instalacion, no se si usas ClickOnce o quizas InstallShield

Comment: la que viene por defecto. Creo un proyecto y cuando lo tengo simplemente publico. Sé que hay otra forma pero nunca me he dedicado el tiempo para aprender ese método.